# Nested arithmetic operation on a list of lists

Tags: c#, nested-lists

I have a `lstCmplx = List<List<CustomClass>>`, the Custom Class looks like this:

```
Public Class CustomClass
{
   Decimal Value {get, set }
   Action Op {get, set } //This is an enum of operations (Add, Multiply...)
}
```

For each list in lstCmplx, I want to get the calculated result of all the items into a single value.
If, for instance:

```
var lst1 = new List<CustomClasss>() 
{ 
   Value = 10, Op = Action.Add
}

var lst2 = new List<CustomClasss>() 
{ 
   Value = 4, Op = Action.Multiply, 
   Value = 6, Op = Action.Subtract //Ignore last action
}
```

If the list has an item (e.g lst1, the calculation uses its Action on the next list in the lstCmplx). If the list has more than 1 item (lst2), the list's items are iteratively calculated based on each item's Action in the lst, ignoring the last action to get a single value.

A typical result will be 34 which is
    10 + [4 * 6]

I'm finding it a bit hard to get an algorithm to chain them together. Please kindly help.

Comment: Okay, that doesn't seem *terribly* difficult then. I suggest you first write a method to handle a single list, and then write code to handle chaining lists together. If you have a specific question on that, you should ask it - but currently, there's no question here.

Comment: I think I understood 10 (if there is one item in the list then the calculated one is the value) and [4*6] (ignore the subtract and multiply them). But why do you add 10 and [4*6]? Do you always sum up all the calculated values? Or is it because of Action.Add in the first list(first item also)? If the latter is true then what if the first list have more than one item?

Comment: Or can we say that for each list we will find not only a calculated value but we will create a `CustomClass` with `Value=calculated as you explained` and `Op=last Op in the list`. And then we will have a new list of `CustomClass` to do the same algorithm.

Comment: If I understand correctly, the calculation suggested by the OP is basically treating the lists as if they where all concatenated into one big list, so why not concatenate the lists and then run the calculation once?

Comment: @Zohar, yes thanks a lot, i did the concatenation and it worked. Thanks.

Comment: @TobbyOlusanya Glad I could help. I'll post this suggestion as an answer, and please mark it as accepted so that other people will know that this is a solved issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand correctly, the calculation suggested by the OP is basically treating the lists as if they where all concatenated into one big list, so why not concatenate the lists and then run the calculation once?